# pass params from app.js to route.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have `app.js` with the following code and I've additional file which is called router.js which handle request's such post/read/etc

**this is the app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
    module.exports = function () {
            var app = express();
             ....
            require('./router/routes')(app, express);
            return app;
        };
```

**The router.js is looks like following**

*/

```
module.exports = function (app, express) {

    var appRouter = express.Router();
    app.use(appRouter);
    appRouter.route('*')
.post(function (req, res) {

            handler.dispatch(req, res);
        })
        .get(function (req, res) {
            handelr.dispatch(req, res)
        })
```

There is a nice way to avoid to pass **two parameters** (app,express) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, change the way you structure your files so you can instead simply require app and express. Now you no longer need to wrap every module in a function or pass any parameters.

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
module.exports = app;

app.boot = function () {
    // require in middleware, routes, etc, then start listening.
    require('./middleware');
    require('./routes');
    // middleware that comes after routes, such as error handling
    require('./middleware/after'); 
    app.listen();
}
if (require.main === module) {
    //move execution to next tick so we can require app.js in other modules safely
    process.nextTick(app.boot);
}
```

**routes.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = require('./app');
var appRouter = express.Router();
app.use(appRouter);
appRouter.route('*');
appRouter.get('/foo', function () {...});
appRouter.post('/foo', function () {...});
module.exports = appRouter; // for unit testing, or you can use this to attach it in app.js instead.
```

---

Additionally, by attaching the boot function to `app`, you can now include this app into another express app and attach it as a router if needed without having to change anything. All you would have to do is require it in, attach it, and then execute app.boot to attach the needed middleware/routes. (useful for unit testing)

Comment: Thanks I want to try it but in the app.js Ive addinal logic where should I put it ? logic like app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
    app.set('production', process.env.NODE_ENV == 'production');
    app.use(logger('dev')); .....

Comment: @Mark it depends. If it needs to run before middleware and routes, putting it outside of boot is fine.

Comment: Ok thanks in the router after the route I've the post/get method where should I put them now ? (please see my update with the new method) , can you provide a complite example  since Im little bit confuse...Thank sir!

Comment: Updated with an example. It's really no different than your code other than removing the function and requiring in app and express.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "nice" way to get rid of the passing of `app`. `express` you could "avoid" by simply adding `var express = require('express');` at the top of the script.

The other option is to instead export your router and mount it in the parent script. For example:

`router.js`:

```
var appRouter = require('express').Router();
appRouter.route('*')
// ...

module.exports = appRouter;
```

`app.js`:

```
var router = require('./router');
var app = require('express')();
app.use(router);
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to pass `express` because you can just require it in `routes.js` without any additional overhead (You already require it in app.js so all you're getting is a reference to the same object).

Furthermore, your router doesn't need to know about app. In fact, it makes more sense to return a router from your `routes.js` and use it from `app.js`. This is called "separation of concerns"; `app.js` handles creation and modification of `app` while `routes.js` handles creation and modification of the routes.

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var routes = require('./router/routes');

module.exports = function () {
  var app = express();
  app.use(routes);
  return app;
};
```

**router.js**

```
var express = require('express');

module.exports = function () {
  var appRouter = express.Router();
  appRouter.route('*')
  return appRouter;
};
```

Comment: Thanks I try what you suggest and Its not stops in the post or get method...any Idea how to adopt it that this is works ?before the changes this works (please see the update in my question with the method which I added)