# Passing function parameter from App.js to Other component in React

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to pass my snackbar component from App.js to other component using the function as follows :

```
const [snackbarOpen, setSnackbarOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const [snackbarMessage, setsnackbarMessage] = React.useState("");
  const [snackbarSeverity, setSnackbarSeverity] = React.useState("");


 const showSnackbar =  (message, severity)=> {
    setSnackbarOpen(true)
    setsnackbarMessage(message)
    setSnackbarSeverity(severity)
    return false
  }
 <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <SnackBarAlert
          open={snackbarOpen} 
          setOpen={setSnackbarOpen}
          message={snackbarMessage}
          severity={snackbarSeverity}
        />
    <Router> 
 <Route exact path="/signup" component={Login}  showSnackbar={showSnackbar}/>
</Router>
  </Router>
        </MuiThemeProvider>
```

Following is what i am trying to do in my Login component :

```
async function handleLogin (props) {
    var apiBaseUrl = `${hostUrl}/user/v1/log-in`;
    var data = {
      emailId: email,
      password: password,
    };
    var headers = {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    };
    axios
      .post(apiBaseUrl, data, { headers: headers })
      .then((response) => {
        //dispatch(sign_in);
        if (response.status === 200) {
          console.log("Logged in successfully");
          props.showSnackbar("Logged In Successfully", "error");
          let string = window.location.origin + "/Home";
          window.open(string, "_self");
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
          console.log("######", err.response);
          var errorCode = err.response.data.status.code;
          var errorMessage = err.response.data.status.message;
          console.log("Message data is", errorMessage);
          if (errorCode === 1008) {
            setresendEnabled(true);
            props.showSnackbar(errorMessage ,  "error");
          } else {
            props.showSnackbar(errorMessage , "error" );
        }
      });
  };
```

Follwing error is coming up while using it :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTWyC.png)

Comment: I think your question already has an answer here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31881187/pass-params-from-app-js-to-route-js

Answer (score 0):

For passing props to a component inside a Route you can use the `render` prop like this

```
<Route
  exact path="/signup"
  render={() => (
    <Login showSnackbar={showSnackbar} />
  )}
/>
```

Comment: To add more this is what is coming in console : Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: props.showSnackbar is not a function

Comment: how are you getting the props in the Login component? can you add the code to your question, please?

Comment: Since my Login component is a functional component i am directly using props.showSnackbar. Do i need to do something in my login?

Comment: I assume your handleLogin function is inside the Login component right? can you put a console.log at the beginning of the component to see how props look like?

Comment: Yes i got it i used props twice thank you for the help